# jQuery stop loop animation method not working

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem to **stop the infinite looping of my animation** using jQuery stop() function. The animation queue is as follows:

1. Move the div *box* 300 px to the right
2. Change div *box* background color to green
3. Double size of div *box*
4. Move the div *box* back to original position (marginLeft 0 px)
5. Change size of div *box* back to original size
6. Change div *box* background color back to yellow

Original properties of div *box*:

1. marginLeft: 0 px
2. backgroundColor: yellow
3. width & height: 100 px

Here is my code tried:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

    #box
    {
        background: yellow;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script> 
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#startBtn").click(function loop(){
         $("#box").animate({marginLeft: '300px'});
         $("#box").animate({backgroundColor: 'green'});
         $("#box").animate({width: '200px',height: '200px'});
         $("#box").animate({marginLeft: '0px'});
         $("#box").animate({width: '100px',height: '100px'});
         $("#box").animate({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});

         setInterval(loop,0000);

      });

      $("#stopBtn").click(function(){

          $("#box").stop(true,true); // stop animation & immediately go to end of animation

      });

  });

</script> 

</head>

<body>

<button id="startBtn">Start</button>
<button id="stopBtn">Stop</button>

<br/> <br/>

<div id="box"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

From what I've understand about jQuery stop() method, the first parameter indicates whether to clear all animations queue. The second one indicates whether to finish up the current animation immediately.

I do not know why when I execute stop(true,true) function, the animation still continues infinitely. (without stopping)

My `stopBtn` jQuery code is supposed to **stop performing any animation and immediately go to end of that animation currently performing before hitting Stop button**.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign an handle to the set interval like so

```
<script> 
     $(document).ready(function(){
     var animHandle;
     $("#startBtn").click(function loop(){
     $("#box").animate({marginLeft: '300px'});
     $("#box").animate({backgroundColor: 'green'});
     $("#box").animate({width: '200px',height: '200px'});
     $("#box").animate({marginLeft: '0px'});
     $("#box").animate({width: '100px',height: '100px'});
     $("#box").animate({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});

      animHandle = setInterval(loop,0000);

     });

      $("#stopBtn").click(function(){

          clearInterval(animHandle); // stop animation at the 
end of queue execution

       });

       });

    </script>
```

Comment: Tried as what you recommend above but not working. Tried on W3Schools online HTML editor. Animations still continue after clearInterval() is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set function outside of document.ready function and it will stop after full iteration, just wait and watch when you click on stop button, wait for 1 iteration atleast.

```js
var intervalId;
var a = function() { 
    $("#box").animate({marginLeft: '300px'});
     $("#box").animate({backgroundColor: 'green'});
     $("#box").animate({width: '200px',height: '200px'});
     $("#box").animate({marginLeft: '0px'});
     $("#box").animate({width: '100px',height: '100px'});
     $("#box").animate({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#startBtn").click(function(){
        intervalId = setInterval(a,1000);
    });

    $("#stopBtn").click(function(){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
    #box
    {
        background: yellow;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }

</style>
</script>
<button id="startBtn">Start</button>
<button id="stopBtn">Stop</button>

<br/> <br/>

<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have found out. Once `stopBtn` is executed, it will **stop the current performing animation and go to the end of that animation**.

First, create a JavaScript function `animationList()` which houses all the animation queues.

Second, declare a variable `animationQueue`. This will store the `setInterval()` request.

Third, create a jQuery `startBtn` click function. This function fires up the animation queue inside `animationList()` using `setInterval()` which sets the interval between each animation for 1 sec.

Lastly, create a jQuery `stopBtn` click function. You have to clear the 1 sec interval set between animations using `clearInterval()` method. Then, execute jQuery `stop(true,true)` to clear the animation queue defined inside `animationList()` (first parameter true) and stop the current animation and go to the end of the animation (second parameter true).

```html
<html>
<head>

<style>

    #box
    {
        background: yellow;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var animinationQueue;

  $("#startBtn").click(function (){
    
    animinationQueue
        = setInterval(animationList,1000);

    });
  
  $("#stopBtn").click(function(){
    
    clearInterval(animinationQueue);
    
    $("#box").stop(true,true); // stop all animination & go to the end of animination
    
  });

  function animationList()
  {
    $("#box").animate({marginLeft: '300px'});
    $("#box").animate({backgroundColor: 'green'});
    $("#box").animate({width: '200px',height: '200px'});
    $("#box").animate({marginLeft: '0px'});
    $("#box").animate({width: '100px',height: '100px'});
    $("#box").animate({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});
  }
  
});

</script> 

</head>
<body>

<button id="startBtn">Start</button>
<button id="stopBtn">Stop</button>

<br/> <br/>

<div id="box"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All functions including animationList(), startBtn and stopBtn must be inside document.ready(function(){})